# Where is this closure leaking memory?

Tags: javascript, closures, cytoscape.js

Ever since I wrote the following closure to wrap around an extension my browser has been running out of memory.

This code (for readability purposes) uses a javascript package called cytoscape which is a graph theory framework. i am trying to register an extension to cytoscape inside of this closure because i wanted the registration to happen independent of the main code.

```
"use strict";

var expandCollapseApi = (function() {
  cdnd = null;
  var api = null;

  // Add Group Boxes
  function addGroupBoxes(setSavedStyle) {
    //debugger;
    if (api) {
      return false;
    }
    .
    .
    .
    .
    .
    api = cy.expandCollapse({ //should this be called before or after?
      layoutBy: null,
      fisheye: false,
      undoable: false,
      animate: false
    });
    cdnd = cy.compoundDragAndDrop(cdnd_enable_options);
    cdnd.enable();
    return true;
  }

  // Remove Group Boxes
  function removeGroupBoxes() {

    if (api == null) {
      return false;
    }
    // add search results if necessary

    cy.style().selector(':parent').style({
      'display': 'none'
    });

    cdnd.disable();
    api = null;
    cdnd = null;
    return true;
  }

  function collapseNodes(nodes, options) {
    cy.expandCollapse('get').collapse(nodes, options);
  }

  function expandNodes(nodes, options) {
    cy.expandCollapse('get').expand(nodes, options);
  }

  return {
    addGB: addGroupBoxes,
    removeGB: removeGroupBoxes,
    collapse: collapseNodes,
    expand: expandNodes
  };

})();
```

Comment: Which closure are you talking about?

Comment: @Bergi I believe the outer one which contains api and cdnd

Comment: The only variable this closes over is `api`. So if there's any memory leakage, it's in there.

Comment: @drakzuli the function that contains the definition of `api` is not a closure. It's part of an IIFE. `addGroupBoxes` and `removeGroupBoxes` are closures (apart from the other functions that trivially close over the global `ty`).

Comment: Btw `cdnd` is never declared, so it becomes implicitly global. Even if intended, that's probably a bad idea.

Comment: Not sure how `cy.elements().forEach()` is implemented, but it looks suspicious that in that loop you execute `cy.add(gb);`, which is an entry that could become part of the iterated collection, and fulfils the condition to execute that again, leading to an infinite loop. Are we talking about a memory leak here, or about code that never finishes running?

Comment: @Bergi Really? the addGroupBoxes and removeGroupBoxes  can be accessed through the expandCollapseApi variable, and those functions can in turn access api. Isn't this a closure? If not would u mind explaining a bit further because i'm new to closures.

Comment: @trincot this is an interesting point. luckily I think the implementation of forEach accounts for this because I haven't ran into any issues with it.

Comment: @Bergi also why is it a bad idea to have cdnd declared as global?

Comment: @drakzuli why are you iterating over `cy.elements()` twice?

Comment: @muka.gergely the parent nodes must be added before the child nodes are iterated through, it's a necessary evil of the extension.

Comment: @drakzuli felt like that :)

Comment: @drakzuli The term *closure* refers to the function(s) that can still access `api` (they *close* over it), not the to the scope in which `api` was declared.

Comment: @Bergi ah I see, thank you

Comment: @drakzuli because global variables in general are usually bad ideas.